# Display products in 2 rows on mobile - Woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce shop and I want to show products in 2 columns on mobile (Now is in one column)

My shop is: https://adidog.pl

I tried with:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
 .cmsmasters_products.columns-3 .product
{
    width: 48.3%;
    float: left;
}
}
```

but they don't display in the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update below css. Due margin padding `48.3%` wan't work. also you need to `clear:none;`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .cmsmasters_products.columns-3 .product {
    width: 46%;
    float: left;
    clear: none !important;
  }
}
```